# Calculating a half vector from eye/camera vector and surface normal

Tags: python, api, opengl, maya

Is there any formula to calculate a half vector from a given eye/camera vector and surface normal/position of an object.

This is the best example I can show of what I mean:

[image: Diagram]

My end goal is to calculate the correct light vector from these two values. (Camera vector and surface normal).

Comment: Vectors need a reference point/surface.  Are the vectors measured as angles from a common line?  What code have you tried already?

Comment: Is the half vector a function of the light vector? If so, you are going to need to know it in order to calculate your half vector...

Comment: Vectors in this case are 3 values that represent a direction from 0,0,0. So 0,1,0 is a vector pointing straight up. My code currently only calculates a camera vector and a surface normal of a selected face on an object.

Comment: I realise adding those two would result in the half vector. I'm trying to calculate the light vector but don't see how i could unless i got the half vector.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't derive the light vector from the surface normal and the cam vector alone - if you think about it, that would imply every unique normal and camera combination would result in a different light position.  However you can derive it easily as

```
light_vect = light_position - face_center_position
cam_vect = cam_position - face_center_position
halfangle_vect = (light_vect.normal() + cam_vect.normal()).normal()
```

where light_position, face_center_position and cam_position are all OpenMaya.MVectors

Comment: You're right in that sense. I'm figured out a method by basically getting the inverse of camera along a plane to get where my light should be to show a specular value. APPRECIATE ALL THE RESPONSES GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to implement specular reflection: Then actually you want to calculate the half angle vector between eye direction and light direction, then take the scalar product with the normal and raise to some power.

The general formula for determining a half angle vector is

```
H(a,b) = normalize(normalize(a) + normalize(b))
```

where

```
normalize(v) = v/len(v)
```

Comment: The problem is I want to get the light vector from the camera eye vector and surface normal.

Comment: Are you trying to do this geometrically or with a surfaceSampler node?

Comment: No i'm doing it with maya api. First I find the aim vector of the camera from the world space value of the selected face. I then find the surface normal(aka vector) based on that world space value.

Comment: @chribis: Are you sure your desired result is the *Light Vector*? The Light Vector is usually given to you as input to perform calculations with. As is the Camera/Eye Vector and the Normal. The only thing I can imagine a use for some half vector of these is specular illumination in a Phong Shader.

Comment: @datenwolf Yes i'm sure. I was trying to get a specular hit at a specific area and to do so needed to create a light that didn't exist.